# what should be placed in the blank and why?

Tags: verb-agreement, subjects

He as well as his friends **_____** going to play cricket in that playground.

Comment: What do you think belongs there? We can't just do your homework for you, and there isn't just one correct answer.

Comment: I think "are" should be placed in the blank space. However I found "is" written in a book of English Grammer.